# Removing list from list. Numbers mirmatch

Tags: c#, list

After I

```
        var old = File.ReadAllText("old.txt").Split(null).ToList();
        var junk = File.ReadAllText("junk.txt").Split(null).ToList();
        var result = old.Except(junk).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(old.Count);
        Console.WriteLine(junk.Count);
        Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
```

I get

```
10791     // old
2431      // junk
5762      // ?????????????????????
```

I would expect 10791 - 2431 to come back with 8360. What can explain the 5762 number?

Comment: Checked if duplicates are present?

Comment: are you sure that there are no duplicates in `old.txt`?

Comment: Thanks guys ,,, good call. Checking ...

Comment: Even if `junk` had `0` items in it, `Except` will still remove any duplicates from the `old` list, for example: `new[] {1, 1}.Except(new int[]{}) == { 1 }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number do not have to match:

- The junk file may contain words that are not in the old file and can therefore not be removed.
- On the other hand the old file could have duplicates that will all be removed.

So the result count can be everything between 0 (if everything is junk in the old file) and the original count of old (if there was no junk at all).